# write numpy array to CSV with row indices and header

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array.

```
values = np.array([14, 21, 13, 56, 12])
```

I want to write `values` in one column of a CSV file, the row indices in another column, and a header. I found this function:

```
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", values, header="Id,Values", delimiter=",")
```

I'm not sure how to add the indices `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. Also, my header turns out to be `# Id,Values`. I'm not sure where the `#` came from. This is what I get:

```
# Id,Values
14
21
13
56
12
```

I want something like this:

```
Id,Values
1,14
2,21
3,13
4,56
5,12
```

Comment: why are you writing two column names and using a delimiter for a single column?

Comment: edited with desired output

Comment: looks like a Kaggle competition csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a better way but I don't think you can do it directly with numpy.savetxt:

```
import  numpy as np

arr = np.array([14 ,21, 13, 56, 12])
np.savetxt("foo.csv", np.dstack((np.arange(1, arr.size+1),arr))[0],"%d,%d",header="Id,Values")
```

*The `#` is the default behaviour as [documented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

String that will be prepended to the header and footer strings, to mark them as comments. Default: ‘# ‘, as expected by e.g. numpy.loadtxt.*

You could use `comments=""` but it is there for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

```
    import pandas as pd
dt = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
dt.to_csv('/test_csv.csv', mode='a', index=True)
```

you can use `to_csv` function in pandas by explicitly set `index=True` or default.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with csv fairly easily, assuming you're ok with a 0-based index:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

a = np.array([14, 21, 13, 56, 12])

with open('out.csv', 'wb') as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['id','val'])
    writer.writerows(enumerate(a))
```